# How to propagate (or introspect) nargout?

Tags: matlab

Is there a built-in way to automatically propagate the `nargout` of a calling function to the called function?  (Or some for a called function to figure out the `nargout` of the calling function?)

For example, say that

```
% foo.m
function [X, Y] = foo()
    [X, Y] = bar();
end
```

and

```
% bar.m
function [X, Y] = bar()
    X = 1;
    if upstream_nargout() < 2
        Y = 0;
    else
        Y = big_nasty_time_consuming_monster();
    end
end
```

Of course, one could always define `foo` like this

```
% foo.m
function [X, Y] = foo()
    if nargout < 2
        X = bar();
    else
        [X, Y] = bar();
    end
end
```

...or define `bar` with an extra argument to carry the caller's `nargout`, but I'm wondering if there's a reasonable way to achieve the same effect without resorting to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`varargout` and `nargout` works as follows:

```
% foo.m
function varargout = foo()
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = bar();
end

% bar.m
function varargout = bar()
    varargout{1} = 1;
    if nargout > 1,
        fprintf('bar: computing second output\n');
        varargout{2} = rand(); % OR big_nasty_time_consuming_monster();
    end
end
```

Then:

```
>> X = foo
X =
     1
>> [X,Y] = foo
bar: computing second output
X =
     1
Y =
    0.5647
```

NOTE: The version of `foo` in the question following "Of course, one could always define foo like this" would certainly work, but this alternative allows you to have a single line in `foo` calling `bar`, rather than another `if`/`else`.  That was the point of the question as I read it.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm a bit puzzled by some details of your proposal, though I see why `varargout` (which I didn't know about--such is the extent of my ignorance of basic MATLAB) would be useful here.  But, after learning about `varargout`, in my naive rendition of your idea, the body of `foo` would have been the single line `[varargout{1:nargout}] = bar();`, and in fact, this one-line "naive `foo`" seems to work when I try it out, at least in this artificially simple example.  I'm sure there are good reasons to avoid this naive approach, but I can't figure them out.

Comment: You mean one line without the `cell` initialization line? Run `bar` with no output arguments (just `foo` on the command line) - it won't work without the `cell` allocation first.

Comment: I tried everything I could think of to break the "naive foo", in the hope of getting a clue for the rationale behind your implementation.  What you suggested in your comment was among the several things I tried, but neither it nor anything else I tried broke the "naive foo"...  (FWIW, I'm using R2013b.)

Comment: Ooops!  I forgot the `1:nargout`! Thanks for the sanity check. No wonder it was harder than it should have been.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any reason to propagate the callers nargout, this should match your requirements:

```
function [X, Y] = foo()
    if nargout < 2
        X = bar();
    else
        [X, Y] = bar();
    end
end
```

.

```
function [X, Y] = bar()
    X = 1;
    if nargout < 2
        Y = 0;
    else
        Y = big_nasty_time_consuming_monster();
    end
end
```

If you really need the calles `nargout` use `evalin('caller','nargout')`, but I would never combine nargin/nargout with `evalin('caller'`, you can easily produce code which is impossible to debug.